# Javascript Gibberish syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm a beginner  in javascript and I use codewars for practice. I always find complete rubbish syntax in the top answers for each exercise. It always looks like: `/|\/\?|/[asd]d++`
What is this? This isn't classes and it's not functions. It looks like complete gibberish.

I don't know how it works and I don't understand it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are probably Regular Expressions, it's a way to match patterns in a string.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression
- https://www.sitepoint.com/learn-regex/

A great tool to test them out on is: https://regexr.com/